# Data Tables in python

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, python-itertools

How do i create a data table that looks like the table below?

```
         (1) (2) (3) (4) 
    (1,2).3  .6   0   0
    (1,3).25  0  .75  0
    (1,4).2   0   0  .8
    (2,3) 0  .4  .6   0
    (2,4) 0  .3  .6   0  
    (3,4) 0   0  .42 .57
  (1,2,3).16 .3  .5   0
  (1,3,4).12  0  .37 .5
(1,2,3,4).1  .2  .3  .4
Rows
```

The rows are all the permutations of an array and the columns are all the values of the array.
The data is each value in the permutation divided by the sum of all the values in the permutation.
The following is the code to get the values.

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
n = int(input("Enter The Amount of Numbers in the List: ")
)
z = []
p = []
q = []
for i in range(0,n):
  x = float(input("Enter the numbers: "))
  q.append(x)
c = list(chain.from_iterable([list(combinations(q,i)) for i in range(2,len(q)+1)]))
results = []
for x in c:
    for n in range(len(x)):
      results.append([x[n]/sum(x)])
```

Comment: first of all, why does the value start with a period/decimal? that is not possible (unless it is a string) and definitely bad practice even if possible.

Comment: I just forgot to write the zero's.